# Dyno in procfile doesnt appear

Tags: heroku, procfile

So I have a procfile, which contains:

```
worker: node index.js
```

and I am wondering why I don't see a new dyno appear in "resources". The bot works on it, the build is successful, but when I want to start the bot I have to run the command "node index.js" in the console and leave it open which isn't convenient.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Procfile which specifies the `worker` process type, you still need to scale up the dynos so it knows how many should be run: `heroku ps:scale worker=1` or however many workers you want.